# How do i Pause a bundled sound file in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, audio

I am now learning on the audio framework of iphone. Just tried to play a sound file and it works fine. Now i need to pause that thing when its playing. How can i do that, Can anyone help me please.

Thanks in advance,
Shibin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be using Audio Toolbox which won't allow you to stop or pause, or change volume. You have to move up to AVAduioPlayer for pausing or stopping of sounds.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you could use AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID); to just stop the sound if that's all you want to happen..